# ASP.net MVC 5 ignoring Date Formatting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date

I have a search form with inputs for date from and date to and uses a Jquery DatePicker

I have tried every combination of the annotations below

I have a view model with the following

```
    [Display(Name = "Date From")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date To")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
```

And a View with the following

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateFrom)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateFrom, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateTo)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTo, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {@class = "form-control"})
         </div>
```

And Script with the following (same for #DateTo)

```
    $("#DateFrom").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: 0
    });
```

web.config has the below

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Ive looked at other issues on Stack Overflow but for me the date is still being interpreted at MM/dd/yyyy for both fields.

The correct format appears to come back to the controller correctly.

I get Client Side Validation Error
The value '13/08/2015' is not valid for Date From.
Anything 01-12/08/2015 will work

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` are only respected when using `EditorFor()` so they are unnecessary in your case.

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Are you saying that you get a client side validation error?

Comment: Yes I get Client Side Validation Error

Comment: With Reference to the referenced Question (in duplicate) I have removed the Date Pickers completely for now and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Not sure what you saying. Do you mean you have removed the scripts?

Comment: Yes, the Jquery.datepicker scripts have been removed (temporaily)

Comment: Don't (the answer I gave showed how to handle this with the datapicker). But if you don't to use the datepicker anymore, then instead of `$.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);` your going to have to replace it with you own validation code to override the default `jquery.validate` method (which validates it using `MM/dd/yyyy`). I do have code for this is you need it

Comment: I tried adding the  $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {... code to above my datepicker declarations.  The datepickers didnt work.   (I have no problem using EditorFor BTW)

Comment: You need to add the script once just after where you include `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (and not inside `document.ready()`) - not inside the datapicker declarations

Comment: Im not currently using JQuery Validate or jquery.validate.unobtrusive, is this something i should add for this to work?

Comment: Then how are you getting those client side validation messages?